# Is the forward chaining CV really suitable for time series?

Tags: time-series, cross-validation

If the time series distribution is non-stationary, we have to retrain our model once in a while (because it must forget the old dependencies and learn new ones). In forward chaining CV we use longer and longer data sequences to train the model anew. Does it make sense if we don't drop old data ?